Examples of expansions of the exponential of a sum of two matrices
The exponential function of a matrix is fundamental in mathematics, physics and beyond.
One can define it using the power series
$$
e^{x} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^n}{n!}  
$$
For any matrix $M$ we can define the exponential of the matrix
$$
e^{M} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{M^n}{n!}. 
$$
It holds that
$$
e^{M} = \frac{e^{M} + e^{-M}}{2} +  \frac{e^{M} - e^{-M}}{2} = \cosh(M) + \sinh(M), 
$$
which is another expansion of the exponential.
In mathematical physics, computing the exponential of a sum of two non-commuting matrices is extremely important, for example because it is what governs the time evolution of quantum systems.
Another example of the utility of having different expansions of the exponential is graphical representations of the Ising model, that stem from from the different expansions above.
The famous Lie-Trotter formula give rise to a useful expansion of the exponential of a sum of two matrices.
$$
e^{A+B} = \lim_{n\to \infty} (e^\frac{A}{n}e^\frac{B}{n})^n. 
$$
A maybe slightly less known formula is the following:
$$
e^{K} = e \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \int_{0 < t_1 < t_2 \dots < t_n} K_{t_n} K_{t_{n-1}} \dots K_1 dt 
$$
where $(t_1, \dots , t_n)$ is the outcome of a Poission point process in $[0,1]$ with intensity 1.
This formula has also been useful in the study of quantum systems.
I am sure there are more non-trivial ways of expanding the exponential. What are some examples?

google search using keywords 'exponential of the sum of two matrices' will give you a certain number of answers.

Interesting question.

Technically, your Poisson point process is a Monte Carlo algorithm to evaluate the time ordered exponential (continuous time Monte Carlo), so for the formula to be exact, you need to add an expected value. The exact formula is:
$$
e^{A+B} = e^{A}\mathcal Te^{\int_0^1B_I(t)dt}
$$
with:
$$
B_I(t) = e^{-tA}Be^{tA}
$$
and:
$$
\mathcal Te^{\int_0^1B_I(t)dt} = U(1)
$$
where $U(t\in[0,1])$ is defined as the fixed point of the integral equation:
$$
U(t) = I+\int_0^t B_I(t')U(t')dt'
$$

The Baker-Campbell-Hausdorff formula gives $Z$ where
$e^Z=e^Xe^Y$  in terms of iterated commmutators :
$$\displaystyle{Z=X+Y+{\frac {1}{2}}[X,Y]+{\frac {1}{12}}[X,[X,Y]]-{\frac {1}{12}}[Y,[X,Y]]+\cdots} $$
where $[A,B]:=AB-BA.$
Of course, if $X$ and $Y$ commute, we have plainly :
$$Z=X+Y$$
